# How to use count of source agents created while model is running to reference a specific schedule column

Tags: anylogic

I'm fairly new to Anylogic and I'm creating a rail yard. The schedule of the time the trains arrive changes daily, but I need to run the simulation over multiple days. So I created a schedule with the hours from model start that each trains arrive, and I made another column as an index column. So I'm using a train source button to source a new train every hour in the schedule, but I need a dynamic number of cars to source with that train depending on which row of the schedule the model is in. So I wanted to make the number of cars a database reference, where the number of trains sourced in the model so far would be used to pick that index number in the index column, and that row would hold the correct number of cars to create. I tried using this code for number of cars in the TrainSource block:

selectFrom(db_table_csx)
.where(db_table_csx.index.eq(LocoCSXSource1.out.count()))
.uniqueResult(db_table_csx.sulphur, int.class)

But I get the error: The method eq(Integer) in the type SimpleExpression is not applicable for the arguments (long).

How can I edit this code so this works, or is there another way to achieve this? Thank you!

[Code Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrTwJ.png)
[Error Received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrqdM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that the method (int) isn't applicable for the argument (long). So you're using the wrong datatype in your argument. You should use an int instead of long.
Since the source.out.count() generates a long, you should cast it to int:

```
selectFrom(db_table)
    .where(db_table.index.eq((int)source.out.count()))
    .uniqueResult(db_table.index)
```